# Is there any way to display screenshot into log.html created by external python lib?

Tags: robotframework

I am beginner of robot framework so that prefer to use external python library with selenium.
Since robot framework log.html is really cool, I want to put my screenshot and test result into robot framework log.html.
Is there anyway to put screenshot created by external python lib into log.html in robotframework?

Comment: Yes, of course. SeleniumLibrary is an external python lib. Just look in its source code to see how it does it.

Answer (score 1):

In general most of the out-of-the-box keywords map to a single Python function. This makes the suggestion from @BryanOakley the right one. Have a look at the code of Robot Framework itself to learn how it does it.

In this case I think you can learn the most from looking at the code of the `Screenshot` [library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Screenshot.html). The Python code for this library is accessible in GitHub. Given that the question is about adding them to the log, the focus should be on two functions starting on [line 230](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/src/robot/libraries/Screenshot.py#L230). The first one adds an image file reference to the log, and the second one adds just the hyperlink.

```
def _embed_screenshot(self, path, width):
    link = get_link_path(path, self._log_dir)
    logger.info('<a href="%s"><img src="%s" width="%s"></a>'
                % (link, link, width), html=True)

def _link_screenshot(self, path):
    link = get_link_path(path, self._log_dir)
    logger.info("Screenshot saved to '<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>'."
                % (link, path), html=True)
```

The actual function `logger.info` that is called, can be found in the Robot Framework API classes and is imported at the start of the file:

```
from robot.api import logger
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I will learn what to do with the code.